# gedit 3 regex search replace plugin port

Tags: regex, gtk, port, gedit, gedit-plugin

So i have been trying to install [gEdit Regular Expression Plugin](http://halfhourhacks.blogspot.com/2008/03/gedit-regular-expression-plugin.html)
in `gEdit 3.2.1` but there seem to be some issues. I have modified the `.plugin` file and now it shows up in the list of plugins.  But when i try to select the plugin from the list, `gEdit` closes.  So i noticed that the plugin import modules from `GTK+2` so i tried changing them to the `GTK+3` equivalents.  Also a lot of the built in plugins code look slightly different than this plugin.  After making changes to `_init_.py`, when i click on the plugin from the list of plugins that is in the list, a error icon shows up next to the plugin name and it gets greyed out.  Has anyone been able to port this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a fork from this plugin some time ago, and now I ported it to Gedit 3. It is versioned / distributed [here](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/gedit-re-search/wiki/Home).